# Stack Overflow reputation issue

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I have asked this question more than one year ago, *[Encoded character buffer storage problem in MySQL varchar using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293979/encoded-char-buffer-storage-problem-in-mysql-varchar-using-c)*. After two or three days I got the answer, so I accepted the specific answer, and got 2 reputation points for accepting the answer. But yesterday I unmarked the answer and then remarked it. I got 2 more reputation points. Why did I get 2 more reputation points?

Comment: To clarify, this happened when you unaccepted / re-accepted the same answer? Or did you originally have the other one accepted?

Comment: @Tim Post, I unaccepted/re-accepted the same answer.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with other questions you accepted already? Hard to believe the system can be tricked so easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/67381/arman?tab=reputation check my reputation before two days, here only the accepted answer is mentioned with +2 but no -2 here.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the bounty system changing. And whether the extra +2 would stick after a recalc.

Comment: I think I have another example of this.  [See user "patrick"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/825952/patrick?tab=stats).   He currently has 3 rep but the reputation tab shows nothing and there is nothing in his activity-list that would earn any points.  He should be at 1, but I'll bet that he checked and unchecked the "Answered" control on his question.

Comment: @Brock: No, that's when you downvote a user at 1 rep and then revoke the downvote. The system automatically awards +2. So yes, theoretically you _could_ get 500 people to downvote first and then one by one remove their downvotes, netting the user 1k! However, that doesn't happen in practice and the user is more likely to get banned for too many downvotes

Comment: I tried this on a few of my questions (both changing the accepted answer and just unaccepted/reaccepting the same one). For me, the reputation gain from the first acceptance disappeared after the I unaccepted it (as it should have).

Answer (score 1):

The original accept was cancelled and the 2 reputation was removed from your account. However, you cast another accept, which earned you +2. In other words, `+2 -2 +2 = 2`, so everything comes out right in the end.

If you search through [your accept list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67381/arman?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_accepts), you'll notice it only shows up for yesterday—the old accept is gone.

Comment: No I earned 4 reputation in the end.